# How to get variable from javascript to php without form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to pass my `topic` variable from this javascript function to my php file faqs.php. I know you can do this with a form, however this function is called when clicking text on the html page. I've tried AJAX but it didn't work for me and I feel like there must be a simpler way.

getFaqs function:

```
function getFaqs(topicId, topic) {
    $("#topic-container").html("");

    //insert javascript to send 'topic' to php file here

    $.getJSON("faqs.php", function(data) {
        if(data == "") {
            $("<div>", {class: "list-group-item", text: "Please add FAQs."}).appendTo($("#topic-container"));
        }
        $.each(data, function(faqId, faq){
            $("<div>", {id: "faq" + faqId, class: "list-group-item", text: faq}).appendTo($("#topic-container"));
        });
    });   
    return false; 
}
```

faqs.php:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

//insert some php to get 'topic' here

if(isset($_POST['topic'])){
    $topic=$_POST['topic'];
    $clean_topic = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $topic);
}else{
    echo json_encode("Please enter a topic!");
}
$musicalinstruments = array("Question1"=>"What is the best musical instrument in the world?", "Answer1"=>"The English concertina", "Question2"=>"How many double bass players does it take to change a light bulb?", "Answer2"=>"None, the piano player can do that with his left hand");
$programminglanguages = array("Question"=>"Why do programmers confuse halloween and christmas?", "Answer"=>"Because Oct 31 = Dec 25");
$varietiesofpizza = array("Question"=>"Should I eat more pizza?", "Answer"=>"Yes. Always.");

echo json_encode ($topic);

?>
```

Comment: Can you add `topics` in JavaScript code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert topic as GET variable in javascript

```
$.getJSON("faqs.php?topic=sometopic", function(data) {
```

And then read that GET variable in PHP

```
if(isset($_GET['topic'])){
```

Answer (score 0):

`$.getJSON` makes a `GET` request while `$.ajax` is the main component to send and communicate with the server. Here's a rough code that would do this just fine.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'faqs.php', 
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { topic: topics }, // topics is your topics varaible from the JS scope
    success: function(data) {
        if (data == "") {
            $("<div>", {
                class: "list-group-item",
                text: "Please add FAQs."
            }).appendTo($("#topic-container"));
        }
        $.each(data, function(faqId, faq) {
            $("<div>", {
                id: "faq" + faqId,
                class: "list-group-item",
                text: faq
            }).appendTo($("#topic-container"));
        });
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
        console.log('error :(');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can send it by url here is the code for it `xmlhttp.open("GET", "phpFile.php?q=" + str, true);
 xmlhttp.send();`
 where `q` is he variable which is used to access the value of perticular variable ,`str` in this case, in php file

Answer (score 0):

If you want use POST:

```
$.post('test.php', { name: "Anna" }, function(response) {
// Do something with the request, data is JSON object.
}, 'json');
```

And read in test.php in POST variable.

```
$_POST['name'] // Anna
```